# success message afer submit an html form

Tags: asp.net, html, forms, submit, response

I have a simple *html* form like:

```
<form id="form1" method="post" target="_self">
<input type="text" name="lastname">
<input type="submit" value="Register" />
<form>
```

I want to replace the whole of this same page with just a success message
from the server, which will also show 'lastname' that was send.
Is there a simple way to do it with from the server side?
(asp.net forms application)

Thanks a lot

Liron

Answer (score 1):

For message and lastname you can pass a query string and display message and another way to submit form using ajax call.

Comment: after successfull saved value to database you can display meassage and lastname on labels.its so easy.

Comment: I have that on the server side:  Request.Form["LastName"] but how can I replace the whole content of the current page, a pure html page

Comment: you can access asp.net html control on sever side by name then display message and lastname.

Comment: but I want to clear all the page and instead show the message. how can I clear a whole pure html page from the server? is that possible or java script is needed?

Comment: yes,you can hide whole form on success using javascript or jquery.